# how to place the "read more" text next to the end of truncated line- Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a text that I have truncated using the css - height and overflow property.

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  padding: 0.5em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.summary {
  height: 47px;
  /* adjust based on line-height * rows desired */
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ellipsis {
  height: 0;
}

.ellipsis span {
  background: white;
  padding-left: 0.5em;
  position: relative;
  top: -1.2em;
  left: 3.2em;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="summary">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
    </p>
    <ul>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test333</li>
    </ul>
    <strong>testststststs</strong>
  </div>
  <div class="ellipsis"><span>... Read more</span></div>
</div>
```

however my issue is when I try placing the "...read more" using he position relative property it does not work: ex below:
http://jsfiddle.net/ctges45w/3/

As you can see the above fiddle the text is floating in middle of the sentence.
http://jsfiddle.net/ctges45w/5/

how can I make sure that the "read more" text always get placed at the end of the line where its truncated regardless of the width of the content?- something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/ctges45w/4/

I have tried looking up at sources on stack overflow with similar issue and those havent or partially worked for me: ex here:[how to place " ...view more " text next to the truncated sentence in a container-Javscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65586856/how-to-place-view-more-text-next-to-the-truncated-sentence-in-a-container)

any ideas?

Comment: [Many, many examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=css+ellipsis+read+more+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: @mplungjan: these examples talk about multi line but does not fix my multi element issue. I have multiple elements in a div and I need ellipsis on the last element. those dont work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget all the `relative` positioning. Just simply put the readmore at the end of the text and style it as you wish.

```js
let summary = document.querySelector('.summary')

if (summary.textContent.length > 100){
    let truncated = summary.textContent.substring(0, 100)
    
    summary.innerHTML = `<p style="margin:0;">${truncated}<span class='ellipsis'>... Read more</span></p>`
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  padding: 0.5em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.summary{
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 47px;
  padding: 0;
}

.ellipsis{
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="summary">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
    </p>
    <ul>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test333</li>
    </ul>
    <p>
      <strong>testststststs</strong>
      <span class="ellipsis">... Read more</span>
    </p>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I could have but the text is dynamically generated and not static- I have just shown this static DOM structure for fiddle purpose. This div container is empty in the beginning and on user inputs the div starts populating the text- I dont have control where to put the Read me text

Comment: Are you able to insert the readme within the `summary` div?

Comment: I can append it as another child to the summary div-like: `<p>
       <strong>testststststs</strong>
       
    </p><span class="ellipsis">... Read more</span>` but not like `<p>
       <strong>testststststs</strong>
       <span class="ellipsis">... Read more</span>
    </p>` as there may not be `<p>` in the content. will this work too if i append it as child to div?

Comment: The former works, see my edit

Comment: I tried https://jsfiddle.net/o7vax1hs/, but I dont see the "read more" text even when there is long text- im missing something?

Comment: You need to scroll down

Comment: hmm thats the problem- I cannot have a scroll- I need to truncate the content and on click of read more it will open up a new container. Scroll cannot be an option, hence I had used the overflow: hidden property. I think i'll try to refer the example posted in the comment above and try them out. thanks for your help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226949/discussion-between-koder613-and-user1234).